# How to avoid "Missing Csrf Token Exception"

Tags: angular, spring-security, http-post, csrf, csrf-protection

When application server access the through the angular2 application below error message printed on the error log.

```
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.MissingCsrfTokenException: 
Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
```

How I can avoid this error by changing the angular2 app and spring security context

Comment: how did you send the csrf token to the server?

Comment: By using ,


{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('myCookieName', 'My-Header-Name')}
{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useClass: MyXSRFStrategy}

As (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#xsrf) mentioned.

Comment: Here what I see n my firefox console 
**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/rest-authentication/login. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)**